# Number/text as output and change color of the number/ text according to logic

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, text

I want to output a particular cell from data which corresponds to a process time associated with a station. For example, if the process includes 3 stations: A, B and C. Say, for gel nails, station A takes 10 minutes to prepare the nails, station B takes 9 minutes to apply the nail color and station C takes another 10 minutes to dry the nails and finish it up. However, the target time is 8 minutes per station. I want the output to be yellow color and if it exceeds 10 minutes, I want the output in red. How can I do that using ggplot?

```
nails <- data.frame(station = c("A", "B", "C"), time_taken = c(10, 9, 11), target_time = c("8", "8", "8"))
```

The expected output is currently created using mode, but I can't edit colors or text size. Hence, I want to do it using R. I would want the ggplot output to be adjusted in font size and color for each station. It could be using any other plot too. Is there a way I could do it? 
Expected output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt to approximate your formatting, though I wasn't sure what font would be a good match.

```
vert_offset <- 6
nails %>%
  mutate(vert_placement = 40 - row_number() * 10) %>%
  mutate(target_time = as.numeric(target_time)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 5 + vert_placement, label = paste("STATION", station)),
            family = "Helvetica", color = "gray30", size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 4 + vert_placement, label = "PITCH TIME"),
            family = "Helvetica", color = "gray50", size = 3.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 2 + vert_placement, label = time_taken,
                color = time_taken > 10),
            family = "Helvetica", size = 16) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "red")) +
  guides(color = F) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. I didn't match your example perfectly, because you can do some of those tweaks on your own. This can be a basic template. The main features are using `geom_label` with a specification of `colour` in `aes`, and then using `fact_wrap` to display the different stations separately.

```
ggplot(nails, aes(x = 1, y = 1, label = time_taken))+
    geom_label(aes(colour = ifelse(time_taken > 10, "Y", "N")), show.legend = FALSE)+
    facet_wrap(~station, ncol = 1)+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank())+
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("Y" = "red", "N" = "gold2"))
```

[image]